# CSS - adjust formatting of list title

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items which I have left aligned against their containing `<div>`.

```css
#list-container:before {
  content: 'My list:';
}
#list-container span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
</div>
```

I want to set the title ("My list") for the list of items to be on the same line of the first item ("item1"), but I do not want to change the left align of the items (I want it to look like this):

```
My list: item1
         item2
         item3
         etc.
```

**not** like this:

```
         My list: item1
         item2
         item3
         etc.
```

I currently am using `:before` to place "My list:," but it is placing it above "item 1" (see above snippet).

Does anyone know of a way to get the title of the list items to be on the same line as the first item without pushing the first list item over to the side?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the answers? Please vote/accept one of them, or update that you didn't get the answer you desired yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not sure why this is the way you want this (and not using regular `ul/li`), but here is what you can do:

1. Make the `content` left-float.
2. Add left padding to every `span` element.

```css
#list-container:before {
  content: "My list:";
  float: left
}
#list-container span {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 54px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like this?

```
#list-container:before {
    content: 'My list:';
}
#list-container span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#list_container span:first_child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-box`

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/844bgccv/)**

```css
#list-container{
 display: flex;
}
.items{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
 <span>My list:</span>
 <div class="items">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like that :

```css
#list-title,#list-container {
  float: left; 
}
#list-container{
  margin-left: 10px;  
}

#list-container span{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-title"> My list :</div> 
<div id="list-container">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```css
#list-container{
  margin:0;
  margin-right:5px;
  float:left;
}
#list-container span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <span>My List:</span>
</div>
<div id="list-container">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by setting the `before` and the `span:first-child` to `display:inline-block` and then set `padding-left` on all of the spans but the first one to make them line up:

```css
#list-container:before {
  content: 'My list:';
  display:inline-block;
  width:56px;
}
#list-container span {
  display: block;
  padding-left:60px;
}
  #list-container span:first-child {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
  <span>item4</span>
  <span>item5</span>
  <span>item6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is put your title in your html. That way, your `list-container` class remains re-usable for other pages where you might require the same styling.

That being said. `:before` and `:after` will pre-pend/append the content provided INSIDE the element for which they are specified. So your title is not being places before your `<ul>` tag but rather inside it,  before your first `<li>`.

Just move your title to the actaul HTML. CSS is for styling and in rare cases shall you need to add content using the `content` property.